# Действие при щелчке в HTML

Tags: javascript, html

не могу понять где ошибка, в браузере отображается но при нажатии нечего не происходит.

```
<meta http-equiv=Content-Type content="text/html;
charset=windows-1251">
<script language="JavaScript" for="document"
event="onmousedown()">
alert("x:"+event.clientX+"\n"+
      "y:"+event.clientY+"\n"+
      "Тэг:"+event.srcElement.tagName);
</script>
</head>
<body lang=RU>
<H2>Определение координат указателя мыши</H2>
<b><p>по идеи при щелчке должен меняться цвет и шрифт текста</p></b>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Никогда не видел подобного применения тега скрипт...

Comment: в смысле??

Comment: объясни  эти атрибуты for="document"
event="onmousedown()".Если ты не знаеш что оно такое ,зачем писать?
http://learn.javascript.ru/obtaining-event-object
http://learn.javascript.ru/mouse-clicks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Этот бред будет работать только в IE.

Надо делать как-то [так](http://jsfiddle.net/yVffq/1/)

Answer (score 3):

Может надо так:

```
document.onmousedown = function(event){
var event = window.event ? window.event : event; 
alert("x:"+event.clientX+"\n"+
      "y:"+event.clientY+"\n"+
      "Тэг:"+ (window.event ? event.srcElement : event.target).tagName);
}
```

?